# issue with grease pencil and tablet pressure

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

After creating a new 2d animation project i started drawing with my tablet (xp-pen artist 12) and i noticed this:

[image: wrong stroke overlay blender 2.8]

as you can see the newer line is covered by the older path.
I don't know if this is just a default setting or a bug but i couldn't find anything about it.

This happens with the tablet pressure strength option enabled in the brush settings, without it the stroke has the same color and this isn't noticeable.

With the same tablet i don't get this using other drawing apps like photoshop.
How can i solve this?

Comment: It looks like a bug, you should report it as a  bug. Help -> Report a Bug.

Comment: It is the same with Wacom Intous tablet.

Answer (score 2):

For those Who are interested i submitted a bug report and got a solution:
It is a stencil setting in the stroke panel, to disable this the feature Is "self overlap".
[Blender stencil setting](https://ibb.co/1sD4HQG)

Credits antoniov developer for clarification.

Comment: Don't forget you can self-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.